# How to install get-iplayer from source file?

Tags: linux, installation, debian, tar

I want to install the latest version of `get-iplayer` in Debian, and I've got its source file, a tarball file, from [here](http://snapshot.debian.org/package/get-iplayer/2.82-2/). However, I don't know what to do with it.

Usually when I come across a tarball, I can run the following commands to build it:

```
tar -xzvf
./configure
make
make install
```

In this case, it seems that this method doesn't fit. What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

There is a package in the official repository, just install it:

```
sudo apt-get install get-iplayer
```

Otherwise if you want to use it from source, you have to download http://snapshot.debian.org/archive/debian/20120605T033409Z/pool/main/g/get-iplayer/get-iplayer_2.82.orig.tar.gz

After extracting, you can run the "get_iplayer" file, you don't need to compile anything as it's a perl script. In order to run it, you have to install perl and perl_lwp but I don't know, which of the following packages you have to install as I can't test it (I'm using Ubuntu and Archlinux): libio-all-lwp-perl, liblwp-authen-negotiate-perl, liblwp-authen-wsse-perl, liblwp-online-perl, liblwp-protocol-http-socketunix-perl, liblwp-protocol-socks-perl, liblwp-useragent-determined-perl, liblwpx-paranoidagent-perl, libtest-mock-lwp-perl

Comment: thank you very much,but,is get-iplayer still working now

Comment: @erical I don't what get-iplayer is doing, but when running from command line, it prints a list of 1039 TV-Programmes. Maybe you want to try "get-iplayer --help" from the command line. But If you don't know why you wanted to install get-iplayer, I can't help you!

Comment: Of course I know its usage,maybe you understood me.Thank you for your help